# How to rewrite url created in slim framework?

Tags: php, .htaccess, web, url-rewriting, slim

I have to rewrite url. I am using slim framework v3 to create api. My current url is like this,

current url = https://apps.example.com/app/v1/myapp/api.php/signin

But i want remove api.php extention so need url like this

https://apps.example.com/app/v1/myapp/signin

I know we have to rewrite url in .htaccess file, i tried same.
my .htacees file is like this

```
##Workign on normal server
RewriteEngine on`
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_POST} !^www.myapp.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myapp.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I tried  solution from slim documentation but not  working..
please help me..
thank u..

Comment: you need to specify `RewriteBase /` where `/` is your root directory

Comment: @anil ok. thanx

Answer (score 1):

Basically you wont need to create separate file for each function in slim framework, slim 3 builtin router functionality will handle this for you.

visit :
https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html